# LongListSelector get selected index

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone, longlistselector

Is there a way to get the index of a particular element from a LongListSelector control? I'd like to remove the object the user has selected but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way of doing this. The LongListSelector's data source (ObservableCollection) can contain duplicates so if I call remove on  it then it would only remove the first instance it comes across instead of the one the user selected.

I can use the ObservableCollection's RemoveAt method but I can't seem to get the index from the  LongListSelector so that I can pass it as the parameter for the RemoveAt method.

Comment: What do you mean by 'can contain duplicates'? Do you mean that your list contains the **same** instance (same reference) of an object multiple times?

Comment: Different reference (two different objects) but they have the same property values so if there was an equality check done on them, they'd match. The Remove method checks for equality so it only removes the first instance it comes across instead of the one the user picked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will help you or not, but if you use an overall MVVM approach in your app, you'd typically have a view model for each item in the list. With that you can define an `IsSelected` property on the item view model and data-bind that to the `LongListSelector` control. Then when you need to delete items you just find all items with `IsSelected` set to `true`.

As a simple example, in one of my item view models I have this property:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Is this location selected in the UI?
    /// </summary>
    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return _selected; }
        set
        {
            if ( value != _selected )
            {
                _selected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged( "Selected" );
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in my XAML item template I have a check box control bound like this:

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected,Mode=TwoWay}"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-10,0,0"/>
```

Hope this helps.